# Filter warnings when module overrides filter list

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, arch

I am fitting GARCH models on data from thousands of sensors, for each day of the month using the [ARCH package](http://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I know that all data are not clean, and the model might not converge for some sensors, and I am OK with that. I plan to deal with them on a per sensor basis later.

My problem is the way Python handles Warnings. As per the [Warnings documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html):

> Conceptually, the warnings filter maintains an ordered list of filter
>   specifications; any specific warning is matched against each filter
>   specification in the list in turn until a match is found; the match
>   determines the disposition of the match.

Which basically means that

```
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

will be appended to the head of the list.

However, in the [ARCH package](http://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), in [/arch/base.py](https://github.com/bashtage/arch/blob/master/arch/univariate/base.py), [line 507](https://github.com/bashtage/arch/blob/master/arch/univariate/base.py#L507) reads:

```
warnings.simplefilter('always')
```

which in essence appends `'always'` to the start of the warnings filter each time a call is made to the model fit method of ARCH. This ensures that the warning is always displayed because I can only add `'ignore'` to the head of the list either before or after placing a call to `.fit()` (which would be overridden by `'always'` in the next call. Since my problem involves thousands of sensors, it prints thousands of warnings which slow the Jupyter notebook to a crawl.

Is there a way to ignore warnings under all conditions? Like a super filter for warnings would be great.

Comment: It's very unfortunate that they're resetting the filter at every call. You could hijack the `warn` function of the `warnings` module, but that's ugly.

Comment: @rubik, I don't know how... And then again, they are importing `warnings` at each call, so unless I change the source code, I don't see how hijacking the `warn` function in my code would help.

Comment: A module is only imported once, then stored in `sys.modules`. I'll outline the solution in an answer.

Comment: (Not related to the question):  Would you mind adding some kind of tag excerpt to arch?

Comment: @Makoto, I did... It is being reviewed. Is there a way I can expedite the review process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're resetting the filter every time, so I don't see any other solutions than hijacking the `warn` function.

When you import a Python module, it gets stored in the dictionary [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) for later uses. Therefore, it is sufficient to import the `warnings` module once and before the ARCH package:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn = lambda *a, **kw: False

# do stuff which might trigger warnings
```

It's an ugly solution, I'll admit. But as a quick hack it should serve its purpose.

---

As a long term solution, I would advise you to open a PR and explain your situation. Simply adding an argument to the function to decide whether to emit warnings or not seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: Please try this solution and report back. I tried it with some ad-hoc files and it worked, but it might be that the ARCH package does additional trickery with warnings. This solution only protects against calls to `warnings.warn`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it successfully. I will mark this as the answer. I opened an [Issue](https://github.com/bashtage/arch/issues/124) with ARCH package on GH. Hopefully they'll get to it soon.